# How to add multiple buttons at the bottom of the screen in ListActivity

Tags: android, button

Question Edited :

I have added buttons at the bottom of screen now my listview is overlapping buttons in spite of putting scroll view. How can i limit my scroll view till button. Below is screenshot and code

Code edited as per suggestion

```
    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/tabs" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_below="@+id/separator" >

            <!-- Scrollview for message data -->

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/formTab"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/formLayout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="5dip" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/add_bt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Home" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/back_bt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Messages" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/back_bt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="History" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/back_bt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Settings" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/back_bt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Support" />
            </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Comment: add buttons as a footer view

Comment: put you send button code in linear layout, set alignparentbottom property to this lineare layout. now just add as many buttons you want in linear layout.

Comment: I tried that. But doing that the listview which is in framelayout scrolls over button.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [ListView#addFooterView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) to add a View at the bottom of the ListView.

Comment: I tried footerView. It shows button at the end of scroll and its very complex with ListActivity. However easy with Activity.

Comment: if you want a hack you can add button below your listview and get the scroll position of listview last child and toggle visibility of button. Hoping its feasible for you

Comment: Okay but discussion is going little off the track. I am actually looking solution in above code if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_below="@+id/tabcontent"` to your Button instead of declaring that the FrameLayout is above the Button, because XML is read from top to bottom, so when the definitions for the FrameLayout are read, there is no Button yet, which means it can't be "above" it.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited code. Can you try in that and show me. I tried your opinion but didn't work well. May b i am doing wrong.

Comment: See my editing: Deleted the RelativeLayout around the LinearLayout as it is not needed. Then removed the alignment statements of the buttons, as they are in a linear layout they will be next to each other anyway, which is defined by the added "orientation" attribute. Last of all I added the layout_below attribute to your LinearLayout which should put it below the FrameLayout

Comment: Nop your suggestion didn't work. I am editing code in question.